Find the number of elements in each group so that the number of these triangles is maximum.
the question
Let 2023 points in space such that there are no three collinearities.  They are divided into 4 groups so that the element numbers in any two groups are distinct.  Triangles are then formed by joining, in all possible ways, three points from three different groups.  Find the number of elements in each group so that these triangles are maximum.
my idea
It took me a lot to understand the problem. The only thing that came to mind when I heard that we have more groups with some points was that we can use pigeon-hole. I don't know how to start. Hope one of you can help me!

So you have distinct integers $ a + b +  c +  d = 2023$, and want to maximize $ abc+bcd+cda+dab$, which likely occurs when they are very similar to each other. Can you take it from here? Nothing to do with PGP.

We want to find $(a,b,c,d)$ maximizing $$M(a,b,c,d):=abc+bcd+cda+dab$$ under the condition that $$a+b+c+d=2023\tag1$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are distinct positive integers.
We may suppose that $a\lt b\lt c\lt d$.
As claimed in Aig's answer, we can say that
$$b-a\gt 1\implies M(a,b,c,d)\lt M(a+1,b-1,c,d)\tag2$$
since
$$RHS-LHS=(b-a-1)(c+d)\gt 0$$
From $(2)$, we can say that if $\max(b-a,c-b,d-c)\ge 3$, then such $(a,b,c,d)$ does not maximize $M$.
So, we see that the maximum value of $M(a,b,c,d)$ is attained when $\max(b-a,c-b,d-c)\color{red}{\lt} 3$, i.e. when $b-a\le 2,c-b\le 2$ and $d-c\le 2$.
We have
$$2023=a+b+c+d\gt 4a\implies a\lt 505.75$$
Suppose that $a=505$. Then,
$$2023=a+b+c+d\ge 505+506+507+508=2026$$ which is a contradiction.
So, we can write $a=505-x$ where $x$ is a positive integer.
Let $p:=b-a,q:=c-b,r:=d-c$ where $p,q,r$ are positive integers. Then, we can write
$$b=505-x+p,c=505-x+p+q,d=505-x+p+q+r$$
and so the condition $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$3p+2q+r=4x+3$$
Since we only need to consider the cases where $p\le 2,q\le 2$ and $r\le 2$, we have the following eight cases to consider :

$(p,q,r)=(2,2,2)$ gives $6+4+2=4x+3$ which is impossible.

$(p,q,r)=(2,2,1)$ gives $x=2$ and $(a,b,c,d)=(503,505,507,508)$.

$(p,q,r)=(2,1,2)$ gives $6+2+2=4x+3$ which is impossible.

$(p,q,r)=(1,2,2)$ gives $3+4+2=4x+3$ which is impossible.

$(p,q,r)=(1,1,2)$ gives $x=1$ and $(a,b,c,d)=(504,505,506,508)$.

$(p,q,r)=(1,2,1)$ gives $3+4+1=4x+3$ which is impossible.

$(p,q,r)=(2,1,1)$ gives $6+2+1=4x+3$ which is impossible.

$(p,q,r)=(1,1,1)$ gives $3+2+1=4x+3$ which is impossible.


So, we have $(503,505,507,508)$ and $(504,505,506,508)$.
Here, we have
$$M(503,\color{blue}{505},507,\color{orange}{508})\lt M(504,\color{blue}{505},506,\color{orange}{508})$$
since
$$RHS-LHS=\color{blue}{505}\times \color{orange}{508}\times\underbrace{(506-507+504-503)}_{=0}+(\color{blue}{505}+\color{orange}{508})\underbrace{(504\times 506-503\times 507)}_{\gt 0}\gt 0$$
where $(s+1)(s+3)-s(s+4)=3\gt 0$ with $s=503$.
Therefore, we finally can say that the answer is $$\color{red}{(a,b,c,d)=(504,505,506,508)}$$

FYI Your presentation can be greatly simplified. See my writeup.

Let there be $4$ groups of points: with $a$, $b$, $y$, $z$ points. Let’s assume that $$b\ge a+2.$$
Then let us move one point from the group with $b$ points to the group with $a$ points. How will the number of triangles change? The triangles with two vertices from the third and the fourth group will stay the same. The number of triangles with two vertices from the first two groups will go from $$ab(y+z)$$ to $$(a+1)(b-1)(y+z).$$
The second number is greater, since $$ab\lt (a+1)(b-1)$$ is equivalent to $$ ab \lt ab+b-a-1,$$ and $b-a-1$ is at least $1$.
So we proved that if some two groups differ from each other substantially, we can make the number of triangles greater. Hence the maximal number of triangles occurs, when all the group sizes are kinda the same. Since we want these numbers be distinct, they are equal to $$504,505,506,508.$$
We can’t make consecutive numbers, so there is the smallest possible gap. Indeed, let us assume that the group sizes are different, but distinct and the number of the triangles can’t be increased.
Let the maximum of the four numbers be at least $509$. Hence the next number is at least $507$. Or else we could make these two numbers closer, thus increasing the number of the triangles. The same way, the next number is at least $505$, and the smallest is at least $503$. Then the sum is at least $503+505+507+509=2024$, which is greater than $2023$. A contradiction.
Assume the smallest number is at most $502$. Then, using the same reasoning, the sum is at most $502+504+506+508=2020$. A contradiction again.
So the four numbers are among $503,504,505,506,507,508$. These six numbers have the sum equal to $3033$. Since the sum must be $2023$, we must remove two numbers with their sum equal to $1010$. Those numbers are either $503,507$, or $504,506$. In the first case, there are
$$504\cdot(505+506+508)+505 \cdot(506+508)+506 \cdot 508= 1534694 $$ triangles. In the second case, there are
$$503 \cdot(505+507+508)+505 \cdot(507+508)+507 \cdot 508= 1534691 $$ triangles, which is less.

Thank you so much for your idea, but I have to questions.  First of all you said that :,,So we proved that if some two groups differ from each other substantially, we can make the number of triangles greater." Didn't we proved that if some two groups differ from each other substantially it means that the number of triangles is less... Also, how did you got to the numbers 504,505,506,508? You just puted them there and I don't know how you arrived to that conclusion...yes, knowing that the numbers are kinda the same is helpful, but there is no proof. Thanks again!

Yes, the number of triangles is less, and we can make it greater by decreasing the groups sizes difference. I will edit the answer now to add a rigorous proof, why numbers are exactly those.

,,Hence the next number is at least $507$." Why cant it be at least 508. We know that ALL the numbers cant be consecutive, but 2 of them can be. Correct me if I'm wrong. I don't really understand what you did in the parts with assuming the min and max of the values....

I don’t see a problem. If a number is at least $508$, then it is at least $507$, so my statement still holds. What I say is that it can’t be less than $507$. Of course, it can be $508$.

Yeah, but how did you get to the result that the second number is at least 507? Also you said ,,let us assume that the group sizes are different, but distinct" what do you mean by it? Arent distinct and different same meaning

Different from $504, 505,506,508$, distinct form each other.

Assume the greatest number is exactly $509$, for the sake of simplicity, and the second to the greatest number is exactly $506$ (less than $507$). Then we can substitute $506,509$ by $507,508$. The numbers are still distinct, but the number of triangles became strictly greater, which can’t happen.

We want to maximize $f(a, b, c, d) = abc+bcd+cda+dab$ for distinct integers subject to $ a+b+c+d = k$. WLOG $a < b < c < d$.
We consider the particular case of $ k = 2023$ at the very end.
Lemma 0: If $\alpha < \beta $ and $ \beta - \alpha > 1$, then $ \alpha \beta < (\alpha + 1 ) ( \beta - 1)$.
Proof: Left to the reader. Either expand the expression, or consider a parabola.
Lemma 1: If $ d - a \geq 5$, then $f(a, b, c, d)$ is not maximal.
Proof: $d-a = (d-c) + (c-b) + (b-a) \geq 5$.
Show that either (at least) one of these terms in the brackets is $ \geq 3$, or (at least) 2 of these are $ = 2$.
Case 1: WLOG $c-b \geq 3$. Then $ f(a, b, c, d) = (b+c)ad + (a+d)bc < (b+c)ad + (a+d)(b+1)(c-1)  = f(a, b+1, c-1, d)$.
Case 2: WLOG $ c-b = 2, b - a = 2$. Then $f(a, b, c, d) = (a+c)bc + (b+d)ac < (a+c)bc + (b+d)(a+1)(c-1) = f(a+1, b, c-1, d )$.
Corollary: When $f(a, b, c, d)$ is maximal, then $$ a \leq a+1 \leq b \leq a+2 \leq c \leq a+3 \leq d \leq a+4$$ and thus $4a + 6 \leq a+b+c+d \leq 4a+9$.
Corollary: The solution $(a^*, b^*,c^* , d^*)$ which maximizes $f(a, b, c, d)$ is uniquely determined via $ a^* = \lfloor \frac{ k - 6 } { 4} \rfloor$ and $(b^*-a^*-1, c^*-a^*-2, d^*-a^*-3)  = (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)$ depending on the exact value of $a+b+c+d - 4a - 6 \in \{ 0, 1, 2, 3 \}$.
Corollary: In this particular case, with $a+b+c+d = 2023$, we get $ a^* = \lfloor \frac{ 2023 - 6 } { 4} \rfloor = 504$. $2023 - 4 \times 504 - 6 = 1$, so $ b^* = 505, c^* = 506, d^* = 508$.
Notes

In Lemma 1, some might argue that the WLOG isn't truly without loss of generality (esp for Case 2), due to the ordering of the terms. However, it should be obvious how the other subcases should be dealt with (increase the smaller, decrease the larger).
This is essentially a smoothing argument on the integers. Without the twin assumptions of distinct and integers, we're guaranteed that it will work (convexity argument of AM-GM). We just have to ensure that after the transformation, we still end up with distinct integers.

